# Targets in the form of {a,b} are not recognized in my Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile:

```
SHELL:/bin/bash

all: euro.n.{a,b}

euro.{a,b}:
        touch euro.{a,b}

euro.n.{a,b}: euro.{a,b}
        cat euro.a > euro.n.a
        cat euro.b > euro.n.b
```

Now if I run `make` twice, the makefile **won't** recognize in the second run that the files euro.n.a and euro.n.b have already been created (and it will be executed again).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem?

`{a,b}` is not syntax recognized by GNU make.

`SHELL := /bin/bash` (you missed `=` there) only affects the syntax of recipes.

---

One alternative solution:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

all: $(addprefix euro.n.,a b)

euro.%:
        touch $@

euro.n.% : euro.%
    cp $< $@
```

Comment: I understand that, but is there a similar syntax recognizeable by make?

Comment: @user86834 Look up `$(addprefix ...)`, `$(addsuffix ...)`, `$(patsubst ...)` in GNU make manual.

Comment: @user86834 Be aware of makefile rules with multiple targets: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html

Comment: GNU make uses the normal POSIX glob(3) and fnmatch(3) functions to do file globbing.  See the man pages for these functions to understand the syntax which is recognized.

Comment: @MadScientist I am sorry for being thick, I cannot connect your statement with the context.

Comment: I was replying to @user86834's question above, by explaining the syntax that make recognizes for globbing ("globbing" is the term of art given to filename matching via `*`, etc. in the shell).  For example: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13